# How to only execute code on certain API level

Tags: android

For instance, this code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {

  myCalendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(
    new OnDateChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        Toast.makeText
        (
          getApplicationContext(), ""+dayOfMonth, 0
        ).show();        
      }

    }
  );

}
```

Gives error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Call requires API level 11
>   (current min is 8):
>   android.widget.CalendarView#setOnDateChangeListener   example.java    /example/src/com/example/example    line
>   20    Android Lint Problem

I understand why I get this error compile-time. But is there any way to mark a source Java class to only be used on certain API level-11? Or surround code blocks with a define/similar so the code is late-bound/jitted only on devices above API level-11? What is the best solution to achieve what I want? (Which is to provide an activity with CalendarView on devices capabile of it.)

Comment: What you're doing is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error described when compiling in Eclipse. (Meaning I can compile and test the code)

Comment: That's a lint error. You can disable it in the preferences. Your app will still run fine.

Comment: Hover the error and add @SuppressLint("NewAPi")

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of TargetApi and SupressLint!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is going to solve your issue,

but what you are using to check version is not working under API 9 
(and you are supporting since API 8).

You should use:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
```

Or as problematic function is API 11, check for "SDK_INT>10"

Then for lint errors on eclipse, do as people comment, disable lint errors or add the @SuppressLint("NewAPi") or the target to that function to 11.

Comment: And you can use `Build.VERSION_CODES` constants to compare with SDK version instead of hard-code : `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {}`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling upon this much later, conditionally executing code based on the API version at runtime is currently a valid way of supporting different platform versions.
See: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms#version-codes

Where it says:

> Android provides a unique code for each platform version in the Build
> constants class. Use these codes within your app to build conditions
> that ensure the code that depends on higher API levels is executed
> only when those APIs are available on the system.

And gives examples:-

Java:

```
private void setUpActionBar() {
    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```
private fun setUpActionBar() {
    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }
}
```